# What are the damage percentages in Super Smash Bros out of?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

I have always wondered this.  Why is the damage done in percents, and what does 100% damage correspond to?

Comment: I've always thought they referred to how much your character gets knocked around when struck. i.e., if you're at 0%, no attack will knock you around. If you're at 100%, you'll be knocked around the base amount. If you're at 200%, you'll be knocked twice as far.

Comment: It's not true how if you're at 0% no attack will knock you around. Most final smashes can kill, or at least damage you severely. Also, smash attacks usually send you flying into the air.

Answer (score 16):

In most ways, 100% is nothing special. I just think of 100% as “about the time when I should start trying to kill the opponent instead of damage them”, though this varies depending on my character, the opponent’s weight, and the stage size.

However, there *is* something special about 100%. Except in *Smash 4*, most **[edge recovery](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Edge_recovery) actions** become **slower** when your character has  100% damage or more. Climbing onto the stage, jumping up, rolling onto the stage, and edge attacking are all affected. Those actions’ animations are different, too. Roll distance changes. And attacks are different, slower but usually stronger. (The action of letting go of the ledge is unchanged).

For example, when Donkey Kong performs an edge attack at *under* 100% damage, he does a flying backwards leap onto the stage and hits enemies with his butt. This places him rather far away from the edge. When Donkey Kong edge attacks at *100% damage or more*, he slowly pulls himself up onto the stage, close to the edge, and slaps sideways. In SSB, this slapping attack does the same amount of damage as the backwards slam attack, but in SSBB, the slap does more damage than the slam.

In Super Smash Bros. 4, this ledge-action-speed mechanic does not exist, but a different mechanic related to 100% damage is added. The [Fairy Bottle](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Fairy_Bottle) item will only heal whoever holds it or whoever it hits when that player has 100% damage or more. Otherwise, the Bottle acts as a throwing item. (Like the Heart Container, the Fairy Bottle heals 100% worth of damage.)

There are other significant exact percentage numbers apart from 100%:

- Characters will not accumulate [hoop damage](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Hoop_damage) past 150%.
- [King Dedede](http://www.ssbwiki.com/King_Dedede_(SSBB)) cannot hurt himself past 150% by charging his [Jet Hammer](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Jet_Hammer).
- [Lucario](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Lucario_(SSBB))’s [aura](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Aura) attacks are weakest at 20% and below, normal at 75%, and strongest at 170% and above.

Source: [“Damage” on SmashWiki](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Damage). I can confirm at least the edge recovery differences from having noticed them in-game myself.

Answer (score 12):

It's [not](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101127135906AAnlnxs) [literally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Smash_Bros.#Gameplay) a percentage of anything; it's just a number that determines how responsive your character will be to a hit. The higher the number, the farther you fly when someone hits you, up to a maximum value of 999.

**Edit:** [Added](http://super-smash-bros.wikia.com/wiki/Damage) [a](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Smash_Bros._Melee#Gameplay) [few](http://wii.wikia.com/wiki/Damage) [more](http://supersmashbros.ign.com/wiki/Super_Smash_Brothers_Melee_%28GameCube%29_information#Gameplay) [citations](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Damage)

Comment: I'm not sure wikipedia and Yahoo Answers are the best places to be citing...

Comment: Fair enough. I've added some more sources to back up my claims.